# Создание xml схемы на python и импорт её в excel

Tags: python, xml, excel

Создаю через патойн xml-схему, чтобы в дальнейшем импортировать её в эксель. Но при импорте самой схемы он не оставляет заголовки, а сразу показывает данные.

Хотелось бы понять, в чём у меня ошибка.

На первом скрине как я хотел бы. На втором - то, что получается.

[image: Вот какое требуется]

[image: Вот так получается у меня]

Код:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
from xml.dom import minidom

i = '12345'

root = ET.Element('interact_entry_realty', guid='atata', version='1')
objects = ET.SubElement(root, 'objects')
obj = ET.SubElement(objects, 'object')
cad_num = ET.SubElement(obj, 'cad_number')
cad_num.text = i
type = ET.SubElement(obj, 'type')
type.text = 'тип'
inf_obj = ET.SubElement(obj, 'information_object')
cost = ET.SubElement(inf_obj, 'cost')
value = ET.SubElement(cost, 'value')
value.text = 'val'
cost_index = ET.SubElement(cost, 'cost_index')
cost_index.text = 'any'
app_date = ET.SubElement(cost, 'approvement_date')
app_date.text = 'date'
det_date = ET.SubElement(cost, 'determination_date')
det_date.text = 'date'


print(minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf-8')).toprettyxml(indent=' ')) #.tostring(root, encoding='unicode'))
ET.ElementTree(root).write('toxml.xml', encoding='utf-8', method='xml', xml_declaration=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё в порядке. Надо было несколько значений туда выгружать.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]